# Remove php extension and parameters using Mod Rewrite in .htaccess to create two seo friendly urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have read ALOT of threads about htaccess rewriting but struggling to get anything to work as I need it to.

I am spinning my wheels here for a few hours.

I have two pages in my folder.

/proposal/index.php
/proposal/dl.php

So normal queries would look like this.

/proposal/?code=123abc
/proposal/dl.php?code=123abc.

But I want to send it to the user like this:

/proposal/123abc/
/proposal/dl/123abc/

Can someone help me with this?

TIA

**NOTE**
I did try the code below which works perfectly on index.php but has no effect on dl.php (if I add dl.php to the mix)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Please invest some more time into revising your question. In its current form it is unclear: is "dl.php" and "download.php" the same? Then please name it the same in the question. What is `/proposal/?code=123abc` meant to be? It does not match the rest of what you explain. Please be more clear in those details.

Comment: What is /proposal/?code=123abc meant to be? this will be index.php. I thought that would be clear as thats pretty much the default file type for directories. I have also removed download.php and edited it with dl.php.

Comment: I doubt that the code you posted has any effect on any of the example requests you name in your question, whether it targets that index.php script or dl.php. That rule does not even try to capture the argument from the incoming request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is the variant you are looking for. Both rules capture the actual argument embedded in the requested URL to re-use it in the internally rewritten request.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [END]

RewriteRule ^dl/([^/]+)/?$ dl.php?code=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?code=$1 [END]
```

Yo may also want to add redirection rules to redirect clients using the "old" URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [END]

RewriteCOnd %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^dl\.php$ dl/%1 [R=301,END]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %1 [R=301,END]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1 [R=301,END]

RewriteRule ^dl/([^/]+)/?$ dl.php?code=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?code=$1 [END]
```

For this it is a good idea to start out with a 302 redirection and only to change it to 301 when everything works as expected.

Both variants use relative paths so that the rules work in distributed configuration files somewhere deeper than the document root of your http server. I personally prefer to implement such rules in the real host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files ("htaccess") for various reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I get a 404 error on both index.php and dl.php now. Its like I mentioned in OP, I have tried a hundred different variations and cannot get this to work. I can only get it to work on the index.php page. The code in my OP works only on index.php not dl.php.

Comment: If you get a 4040 that means that index.php and dl.php are not in the root of your http server. You did not mention that in your question.

Comment: I modified the answer to use relative paths. Less robust, less efficient, but apparently you are using such a setup.

Comment: Appreciate your help, even though your comments are a little passive-aggressive, grateful for your help all the same.

Comment: I have tested your revised code and it also works. So as a courtesy, as your code is "tidier" than mine, I will accept yours as the accepted answer. Thank you, Christian.

Comment: OK, I do apologize if I appeared to be aggressive. I think I understand what you mean... My issue is that many questions here lack precision and I try to point out those details so that people understand why the answers they receive won't immediately work just like that. But I understand that this probably does not work. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this worked.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dl/(.*) dl.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Now I am able to call the pages like this:

/proposal/123abc/
/proposal/dl/123abc/

All I did was add the line below to my original code.

```
RewriteRule ^dl/(.*) dl.php/$1 [L]
```

The structure of my subdirectory is as follows:

/proposal/.htaccess
/proposal/index.php
/proposal/dl.php

Now I am able to provide nice URLs to the clients for these two files and call up their content using my parameter like:

/proposal/123abc
/proposal/dl/123abc

Which would be like this in a normal way

/proposal/index.php?code=123abc  or  /proposal/?code=123abc
/proposal/dl.php?code=123abc